# Mapping key and value to new keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, key-value

Array of dictionaries should be converted simpler form.

```
 data = [{A:1},{B:2},{C:3}] 
 data = {A: 1, B: 2}
 data = ["0":{ A : 1, B : 2 , C : 3}]
```

Both are completely different datasets. I'm trying to map it also like below format.
The above should become like

```
 data = [
  {
    name: "A",
    y: 1
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    y: 2
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    y: 3
  }
];
```

I tried this following approach but it's wrong

```
name = {}
data.forEach(function(k,x){
    return name['name'] = k , name["y"] = x 
})
```

Please suggest me a better approach.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand in your code sample above, where it says `and data = {A: 1, B: 2}`. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` each object's `entries` to extract the key and the value, and return an object with `name` and `y` keys:

```js
const data = [{A:1},{B:2},{C:3}]
const output = data.map(item => {
  const [name, y] = Object.entries(item)[0];
  return { name, y };
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: How do I do the same thing for 3d data format when the whole dictionary is the value of a single key?

Comment: Like what? Give an example of an input and an output, in a new question (avoid [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)) If it's just your `data = ["0":{ A : 1, B : 2 , C : 3}]`, then just select the first array item first

Answer (score 0):

You yould could chekc the data format and if it is not an array, build one and reduce the array by taking the objetcs and create for each key/value a new object for the result set.

```js
function simple(data) {
    return (Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data]).reduce((r, o) => [...r, ...Object.entries(o).map(([name, y]) => ({ name, y }))], []);
}

console.log(simple([{ A: 1 }, { B: 2 }, { C: 3, D: 4 }]));
console.log(simple({ A: 1, B: 2 }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keys (A, B, etc) are guaranteed to be unique throughout the array, then everything becomes simpler.

```js
const data = [{A:1},{B:2},{C:3}];
const merged = Object.assign({}, ...data);
const newData = Object.entries(merged)
  .map(([name, y]) => ({ name, y }));
console.log(newData);
```

However, if the keys aren't guaranteed unique, then refer to CertainPerformance's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, use Object.keys() which is widly supported

```js
let data = [{A:1},{B:2},{C:3}];

data = Object.assign({}, ...data);

data = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({ name: key, y: data[key] }));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Note that `Object.assign(...data)` mutates the first element of the input array, which can cause weird, hard-to-detect bugs in your code. To avoid this, I recommend using `Object.assign({}, ...data)`.

Comment: @greim Used `Object.create()` and there is no such issue

Comment: That isn't how `Object.create()` works. It throws an error now. I think you were on the right track before.

Comment: Thanks @greim for reporting error, it should work but you are right, assign is better choice here

Answer (score 0):

```
you can implement like this
```

```js
 var data = [{A:1},{B:2},{C:3}];
 
 var reformattedArra = data.map(obj => {
  let val = {};
  val.name = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  val.y = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
  return val;
 })
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(reformattedArra));
```